# Weird iOS5 glitch when keyboard appears after selecting textfield

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiscrollview, uitextfield, uikeyboard

When selecting a textfield in iOS5 a weird arrow moves from the top left to bottom right of the screen when the keyboard appears. This only happens in iOS5 on the device and the simulator. When running with iOS4 it works as expected.

It only happens the first time the app runs, when i dismiss the keyboard and select the textfield again the arrow isnt visible. I have to restart the app to see it again.

Notes:
Ive posted a video to display what i'm getting http://youtu.be/4Ju2-wQ3hVY

I've tried stripping out other classes and creating a new blank nib with a textbox only but the problem still persists within my project. Creating a new project with xcode 4.3, the problem isnt visible. I've also tried with zombies enabled and didnt get any errors.

Are there new project / build settings that might conflict with the older versions?

Answer (score 0):

This arrow looks like bug to me. I suggest you to file a bug report to Apple and post your issue to http://devforums.apple.com, where *maybe* issue will be notice by Apple employees and you may get more details on this.